# Magento 1.9 coupon code showing it's applied, but it's not working

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

We are facing Magento coupon code issue, some time it's showing coupon code
applied but it does not impact on cart total price change and not show discount amount as well, but if we try on other system some time it's working fine as expected.

We have checked cookies, server time zone, Magento timezone etc., everything seems fine.

I did not get any log errors either.

Is there any how we can get error why this happening , as this happen only some time, not always?

Our Magento version is 1.9.3.6. We upgraded few month ago from Magento 1.7 to 1.9.3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check cache. Disable Magento cache and check on different systems. If problem resolved then you can refresh cache by cron in every 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes i have checked by this, but sometime it's working . Usually it make issue on chrome in window 10 and IOS.
by the way can you please mention here to refresh cache file, which we need to run by cron in every 5 minutes?